# QIdentityProxyModel display empty rows

Tags: c++, qt

I've implemented `QIdentityProxyModel` like this:

```
class ProxyModel : public QIdentityProxyModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ProxyModel(QObject *parent)
    {
        entriesPerPage = 3;
        page = 1;
    }

    inline int getEntriesPerPage() const
    { return entriesPerPage; }
    inline void setEntriesPerPage(int value)
    { entriesPerPage = value; }

    inline qint64 getPage() const
    { return page; }
    inline void setPage(const qint64 &value)
    { page = value; }

    inline int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override{
        Q_UNUSED(parent)
        if(!sourceModel())
            return 0;

        return entriesPerPage * page <= sourceModel()->rowCount()
                ? entriesPerPage
                : sourceModel()->rowCount() - entriesPerPage * (page - 1);
    }

    inline int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override{
        Q_UNUSED(parent);
            return 6;
    }

    QModelIndex ProxyModel::mapFromSource(const QModelIndex &sourceIndex) const
    {
        if(!sourceModel() && !proxyIndex.isValid())
            return QModelIndex();

        return sourceIndex.isValid()
                ? createIndex(sourceIndex.row() % entriesPerPage, sourceIndex.column(), sourceIndex.internalPointer())
                : QModelIndex();
    }

    QModelIndex ProxyModel::mapToSource(const QModelIndex &proxyIndex) const
    {
        if(!sourceModel() && !proxyIndex.isValid())
            return QModelIndex();

        QModelIndex remapped = createIndex(proxyIndex.row() ,
                                           proxyIndex.column(),
                                           proxyIndex.internalPointer());
        return QIdentityProxyModel::mapToSource(remapped);
    }

private:
    int entriesPerPage;
    qint64 page;
};
```

When I insert a row in the `sourceModel()` with index more then `entriesPerPage`, view displays empty rows, so that row number is more then `entriesPerPage`, although rowCount() return number equal to `entriesPerPage`.

[image]

How can I get rid of empty rows?

Comment: That has probably to do with `rowsAboutToBeInserted` and `rowsInserted` signals. Views will react on them and provide new rows for the newly created data. I don't think you can intercept these signals, but you could use reset the model if the row are outside of your paging window (`beginResetModel`, `endResetModel`). That causes the views to completely reload the data

Comment: @king_nak I tried to overload `insertRows` and `insertRow` methods to follow where model takes rows, but this class never uses this methods. Can  it emit `rowsAboutToBeInserted` and `rowsInserted` signals, not inserting rows?
And which place should I put `beginResetModel`, if I overload only const methods?

Comment: You insert into the source model, that causes the Identity model to emit the signal, and I found no way to prevent that in that case (I checked the source). One option is to not insert into the source model but your proxy, and handle everything yourself. But you could try and connect the `rowsAboutToBeInserted` and `rowsInserted` to the `modelAboutToBeReset` and `modelReset` singals... But that's hacky.

Comment: Btw, inlining is not worked with virtual methods.

Comment: And you forgot to call parent ctor (of `QIdentityProxyModel`) in your ctor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First. It is a bad practice to override `rowCount`/`mapFromSource` for `QIdentityProxyModel`. I propose you to use `QAbstractProxyModel` to have more clear code.

Main. Your problem is in `getEntriesPerPage`/`setPage` methods. You need to call `beginResetModel`/`endResetModel` after updating such data.

```
inline void setPage(const qint64 &value)
{
    beginResetModel();
    page = value;
    endResetModel();
}
```

Offtopic: it is pretty cool, that you have to code with Qt in BSUIR. Who is your teacher?

Comment: 2) Based on your logic - when you insert some rows to your source model, then all indexes of proxy model became invalid. So the simpliest way is to reset proxy model each time when your structure changes. Or you can manually track all indexes during insertion and write a complex logic to do nesessary updates. As I see from your screenshot you don't have a lot of data. Event 10k records is too few. So, keep it simple, just reset proxy model on each structure modification of source model.